# enviar un JSON por POST con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, post

A ver...según los comentarios tendría que editar el hilo, pero por más que lo haga nada...

Tengo que enviar un json por post, y al enviarlo yo tendría que recibir uno en el que me diria si el login es correcto o incorrecto.

Aquí el formulario del login:

```
<form name="login" action="">
    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="User">
    <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit" id="send" onclick="sendForm()">Enter</button>
    <div class="moreoptions">
        <div class="ico">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <a href="#">I forgot my password</a>
        </div>
        <div class="ico">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <a href="#">Register</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Y esta es la función javascript que llama al darle al button #send

```
function sendForm(){
    var fpU = ROT47(document.forms[0].elements[0].value);
    var fpP = ROT47(document.forms[0].elements[1].value);


var objJSON = {
    pfd: "login",
    fpU: fpU,
    fpP: fpP,
    browserInfo: {
        appCodeName: navigator.appCodeName,
        appName: navigator.appName,
        appVersion: navigator.appVersion,
        cookieEnabled: navigator.cookieEnabled,
        language: navigator.language,
        platform: navigator.platform,
        userAgent: navigator.userAgent
    },
    datasite: {
            "@accountID": "2",
            "@siteID": "3"
    }
};

$('#send').click(function(){
    var data = objJSON;
    $.ajax({
        url : 'https://www.evstest.com/G3v1LastVersion/portal/portal_action.php',
        data : data,
        method : 'post', //en este caso
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(response){
            alert("funciona bien");
        },
        error: function(error){
            alert("No funciona");
        }
    });
});
}
```

He probado a hacer un alert para ver el JSON si está bien construido y si.
luego el código que supuestamente lo manda, parece que no haga nada, pues no se ejecutan las lineas de código de los alert, donde si dice que se ha enviado o no.

Espero que así os sirva para intentar ayudarme. Un saludo y gracias de nuevo

Comment: De primeras me imagino que quieras enviarlo de manera natural, sin AJAX ni nada, HTML y JS, cierto? Si es así deberías de añadir un campo al formulario que lo contenga, puedes utilizar un campo oculto <input name="json" type="hidden"> y ahí mediante JS guardar el JSON en formato String.

Comment: y si el contenido del json depende de loq ue haya en los datos del login ??, hago que meta el json dentro en el value del hidden al darle al botón enviar ?

Comment: Perdona que no te leí, estaba escribiendo la respuesta. Efectivamente, modificando un poco mi respuesta antes de enviar el formulario podrías buscar en otra función o lo que quieras el contenido del JSON, pasarlo a string y asignárselo al campo hidden. Fíjate bien que el JSON esté bien formateado, existen herramientas de validación.

Comment: Una pregunta, me encuentro en que el JSON que tengo que construir ( tengo uno de ejemplo ) en la parte final tengo esto: **"datasite":{"@accountID":"2","@siteID":"3"}}** pero lo intento primero crear como un objeto js normal, pero al darle al nombre @nombre me lo ve como error.. pero el tema es que tiene que ir a sí

Answer (score 4):

Debes a todos tus elementos html entregarles una `id`

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="user" placeholder="E-mail">
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Password">
```

Al boton de tu formulario tambien dale una `id`

```
 <div class="ico" id="registrar"
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <a href="#">Register</a>
        </div>
```

En tu codigo JS debes capturar el evento click de tu boton

jQuery

```
$('#registrar').click(function(){
        var data = { email : $('#email').val(), password : $('#pass').val() };
        $.ajax({
                url : 'tu_url'
                data : data, 
                method : 'post', //en este caso
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(response){
                       //codigo de exito
                },
                error: function(error){
                       //codigo error
                }
        });
});
```

Javascript

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "tu_url";
var email = document.getElementById('email');
var password = document.getElementById('pass');
http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
http.open("POST", url, true);

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) { 
       //aqui obtienes la respuesta de tu peticion
       alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(JSON.stringify({email:email, password: password}));
```

Comment: como le dije a otro forero: me encuentro en que el JSON que tengo que construir ( tengo uno de ejemplo ) en la parte final tengo esto: "datasite":{"@accountID":"2","@siteID":"3"}} pero lo intento primero crear como un objeto js normal, pero al darle al nombre @nombre me lo ve como error.. pero el tema es que tiene que ir a sí

Comment: Por que haces un submit de tu formulario si lo que vamos a hacer es un ajax? Lo otro intenta sacar JSON.stringify para ver que resultado hay

Comment: No lo ha dicho, pero con ambas soluciones (jquer y js) se ahorraria el problema que tiene y seria la solucion a lo que el necesita no crees? Mostrar un mensaje despues de la ejecucion de otro archivo dependiendo de la respuesta que este entregue?

Comment: Obviamante , yo respondi a la primera pregunta dandole el mejor de los casos para lo que el necesitaba, sin embargo si se ve asi el panorama mejor que reeplantee bien su pregunta y ver ayudarlo. Saludos @aldanux  por los alcances

Comment: El caso es que no se si con vuestro ejemplo se envia correctamente pues no recibo nada al enviarlo, entonces no se si funciona o no. Y debería recibir un jSON parecido a este: **{"url":"..\/..\/..\/portal\/genericModule.php?cl2=MzY1Njk1OGNlNDQ1OWU1MzQ2MDc3Nj g3NmI5NWJmOTc=","data":"ok","lp":"MzY1Njk1OGNlNDQ1OWU1MzQ2MDc3Njg3NmI5 NWJmOTc="}**

Comment: Pero el JSON lo armas tu mismo, tu dejaste un formulario con 2 inputs por lo tanto el json que te mostre en la respuesta corresponde a eso. Por otro lado hacer un post por javascritp o por jquery hace un llamado a un archivo que dentro tiene una funcionalidad que trabaja con los datos que tu envias y devuelve un valor. No haz como tienes ese archivo ni nada, la solucion que te damos en el foro son dos 1) Guiarte de la mejor manera a solucionar un problema o 2) ver tus errrores y corregirlos jamas vamos a adivinar tu codigo para ver en q falla.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es enviarlo de manera natural podrías hacer esto:

- Añadir un campo oculto antes del botón submit: `<input type="hidden" name="json">`
- Modificar un poco tu función de envío:

```html
function sendForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sendJSON = "{...
    sendJSON = JSON.stringify(sendJSON);

    document.getElementsByTagName('json').value = sendJSON;
    document.form[0].submit();
}
```

Fíjate bien en pasar previamente el JSON a string y que éste esté bien formado para que no surja ningún error.

Comment: el tema es que lo tengo que mandar a una dirección externa. como podría hacerlo ?. Mi trabajo consiste en enviar un JSON a una dirección externa y esta me devuelve otro JSON

Comment: Deberías poner la dirección deseada en action="", si quieres que te devuelva algo deberías usar algo como AJAX.. pero AJAX está restringido únicamente al dominio desde el que envías. Para hacer peticiones externas (cross-domain) existe lo que se llama JSONP. Para saber de ello estaría mejor si abrieses una nueva pregunta o modificases ésta pues el tema no tiene nada que ver.

Comment: con la extension firebug no puedo ver lo que envio y recibo ??

Comment: Personalmente no utilizo Firebug, pero de todos modos así no vas a recibir nada pues no hay comunicación en los 2 sentidos. Sólo envías.